# Dataset size for recommendation algorithm

Tags: dataset, weka, recommendation-engine

I am working on creating a recommender system,using **weka**. What i read about dataset on internet so far is 
It should have more data for recommendation to be good.
I wonder what if I am trying to recommend something about which we can't have large amount of data.
For example if want to create a **Park or hospital recommender system** for a particular city. It wouldn't have more than 100 entries. So is it ok to do it with **small datasets**?

Comment: How many attributes are going to be contained in the dataset?  Is it a complex problem?  It is difficult to say without further information.

Comment: Your recommender system will work if you trained it with small datasets (say 100), but the accuracy may not be as good as 1000 datasets.

Comment: @MatthewSpencer it would have 5-7 attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51490/how-large-a-training-set-is-needed), there are some guides or rules-of-thumb that could be used for preparing sufficient data for the model.  Some of the advice here included:

- At least six times the number of features as training cases
- At least three times the number of features per class

Please note that these are only rules of thumb, and may or may not be enough depending on the complexity of your data.  Based on the recommendations outlined in this article, 100 cases might just be enough, but as Ramanan R stated, more cases would likely be better.

Hope this Helps!